# Having trouble writing my fmap

Tags: haskell, functor

I am trying to write an fmap for this type

```
data Triangle a  = Triangle {t0 :: Point a, t1 ::  Point a, t2 ::  Point a}
```

where Point is defined as

```
data Point a = Point {px :: a, py :: a, pz :: a}
```

And my instance def is

```
instance Functor Triangle where 
    fmap f (Triangle v0 v1 v2) = Triangle (f v0) (f v1) (f v2)
```

I am getting the following compliation error and I can't figure out why

```
 C:\Scripts\Haskell\Geometry.hs:88:1:
     Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = Point a
     When generalising the type(s) for `fmap'
     In the instance declaration for `Functor Triangle'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
instance Functor Point where
    fmap f (Point v0 v1 v2) = Point (f v0) (f v1) (f v2)

instance Functor Triangle where
    fmap f (Triangle v0 v1 v2) = Triangle (fmap f v0) (fmap f v1) (fmap f v2)
```

In the Triangle instance, `f` is `a -> b`. We have to convert it to `Point a -> Point b` first. Then we can make `fmap f` transform `Triangle a` to `Triangle b`. (Observe you're applying `f` to 9 objects, if I understood your intention correctly) [edit: was 27]

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize that the fmap had to be applied to the components like that. I realize the same is true with Traversable. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer gives you a correct solution, but it might be helpful to be more explicit about what's going on here. The type of `fmap` is

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So the type inference for your `instance` declaration proceeds as follows:

1. In `fmap f (Triangle v0 v1 v2)`, `f` must have some type `a -> b` and `(Triangle v0 v1 v2)` must have type `Triangle a`.

   - By the definition of `Triangle`, `v0`, `v1`, and `v2` must have type `Point a`.
   - Since `f` is applied to `v0`, `v1`, and `v2`, its argument type `a` must be `Point a`.
   - Oops, `a = Point a` is unsatisfiable.

Why does the definition `Triangle (fmap f v0) (fmap f v1) (fmap f v2)` work? :

1. In `fmap f (Triangle v0 v1 v2)`, `f` must have some type `a -> b` and `(Triangle v0 v1 v2)` must have type `Triangle a`.

   - By the definition of `Triangle`, `v0`, `v1`, and `v2` must have type `Point a`.
   - Assuming `Point` is an instance of `Functor`, as above, `fmap f v0` must have type `Point b`, where `b` is the result type of `f`. Likewise for `v1` and `v2`.
   - Hence `Triangle (fmap f v0) (fmap f v1) (fmap f v2)` has type `Triangle b`.
   - QED.

Comment: I find this kind of walk-through very valuable when learning how type inference works, thanks Chris!

Answer (score 2):

Btw, an interesting property of `Functor` is that there is only one possible instance to make that will satisfy the [Functor laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Properties).

Better yet, this instance can be automatically produced for you using the [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/derive) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.DeriveTH (derive, makeFunctor)

data Point a = Point {px :: a, py :: a, pz :: a}
$(derive makeFunctor ''Point)

data Triangle a  = Triangle {t0 :: Point a, t1 ::  Point a, t2 ::  Point a}
$(derive makeFunctor ''Triangle)
```

Imho this is a win partially because if you decide to change the definition of `Triangle`, its `Functor` instance is maintained automatically for you.

Comment: The derive version in cabal was not functional at the time that I wrote this question. However, I am now using the darc version for this stuff.

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff: yeah I guess I was using the darcs version as well