# functor on data type with two constructors - occurs check

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a data type

```
data Pnt2d i v = Pnt2d {_p2id:: i, _v2:: V2 v}
```

and would like to construct a functor to apply to the second component (V2) as

```
instance Functor (Pnt2d i) where 
fmap f (Pnt2d i v) = Pnt2d i (f v)
```

but I get an "occurs check". I understand that I can build Functors only on the second parameter of a multi-parameter data type - which is the case here. What is special and probably the cause of the error is that the second type parameter is a type parameter of the inner (V2) type.  It seems related to [Functor error when using a data inside a data: "cannot construct the infinite type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480866/functor-error-when-using-a-data-inside-a-data-cannot-construct-the-infinite-ty;) I checked the type of the functor when written separately and it seems correct. The answer in [Having trouble writing my fmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910885/having-trouble-writing-my-fmap) suggests that two nested functors were necessary - is this the case here?

I do not see, how to construct the functor in this case. I tried with Lenses, but to no avail and would be interested to see what the solution is with/without using Lenses.

```
src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:35: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ V2 b
    • In the second argument of ‘Pnt2d’, namely ‘(f v)’
      In the expression: Pnt2d i (f v)
      In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (Pnt2d i v) = Pnt2d i (f v)
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> b (bound at src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:10)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> Pnt2d i a -> Pnt2d i b
          (bound at src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:5)
    |
119 |     fmap f (Pnt2d i v) = Pnt2d i (f v)
    |                                   ^^^

src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:37: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ V2 a
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘v’
      In the second argument of ‘Pnt2d’, namely ‘(f v)’
      In the expression: Pnt2d i (f v)
    • Relevant bindings include
        v :: V2 a (bound at src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:21)
        f :: a -> b (bound at src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:10)
        fmap :: (a -> b) -> Pnt2d i a -> Pnt2d i b
          (bound at src/Uniform/Point2d.hs:119:5)
    |
119 |     fmap f (Pnt2d i v) = Pnt2d i (f v)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your instance, `f` has type `a -> b`, but you're using it as if it has type `V2 a -> V2 b`.

You need to lift `f` using `fmap` so that it has the type you want.

```
instance Functor (Pnt2d i) where 
    fmap f (Pnt2d i v) = Pnt2d i (fmap f v)
```

With lenses, you could do:

```
instance Functor (Pnt2d i) where 
    fmap f = v2 %~ fmap f
```

Comment: This is a convincing answer. Thank you.  - I found, after trying some of the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910885/having-trouble-writing-my-fmap - to use the automatic derivation of the functor and it constructed two one nested into the other which works as well. I think this is equivalent to your use of fmap inside of fmap.

Comment: I still wonder if there is an elegant solution with Lenses?